# How to User Login With Wordpress using React Native

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

I am having troubles to find any useful code snippets or documentation on how to code a REST User Login with React Native to Wordpress.

Anything, that could help me achieving this, the easiest way?

Comment: Hi Jürgen Gunz Same question. Did you resolve this?

Comment: I'll make a tutorial on this soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the render()  method of your React Native component, create a Form with input fields for Username and Password.

```
this.state = {
    validating: false
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content>
                <Form>
                    <Item floatingLabel>
                        <Label>Email</Label>
                        <Input onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})} />
                    </Item>
                    <Item floatingLabel last>
                        <Label>Password</Label>
                        <Input secureTextEntry onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password:text})} />
                    </Item>
                    <Button block success style={{ marginTop: 50 }} onPress={() => {
                        if( this.state.email && this.state.password ){
                            this.validate();

                        }
                    }} >
                        <Text>Authenticate</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Then on form submit, the data gets POSTed to a WordPress API server where we check if credentials are correct and throw an error if incorrect, if the credentials are correct – we generate a token which is just a combination of strings and numbers (your choice). This token will then be stored in in the wp_usermeta table, this way you can do checks every time a user will access your mobile app.

Login to your server via your favorite FTP program and then the root directory of WordPress, create a PHP file called “authentication.php” then add the following code:

```
<?php 

require_once('wp-load.php');

$response = array(
    'data'      => array(),
    'msg'       => 'Invalid email or password',
    'status'    => false
);

/* Sanitize all received posts */
foreach($_POST as $k => $value){
    $_POST[$k] = sanitize_text_field($value);
}

/**
 * Login Method
 *
 */
if( isset( $_POST['type'] ) &&  $_POST['type'] == 'login' ){

    /* Get user data */
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['email'] );

    if ( $user ){
        $password_check = wp_check_password( $_POST['password'], $user->user_pass, $user->ID );

        if ( $password_check ){
            /* Generate a unique auth token */
            $token = MY_RANDOM_CODE_GENERATOR( 30 );

            /* Store / Update auth token in the database */
            if( update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'auth_token', $token ) ){

                /* Return generated token and user ID*/
                $response['status'] = true;
                $response['data'] = array(
                    'auth_token'    =>  $token,
                    'user_id'       =>  $user->ID,
                    'user_login'    =>  $user->user_login
                );
                $response['msg'] = 'Successfully Authenticated';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now that we have a token, we pass it back to our mobile app as a response. Our mobile app should then be able to receive and store the token (and any other data you want) to our mobile device storage via AsyncStorage, this way, every time the user opens your mobile app, our application will just check the storage if it has a currently logged-in user (Persistent Login).

```
validate(){
    this.setState({ validating: true });

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type', 'login');
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);
    formData.append('password', this.state.password);

    return fetch('http://example.com/authentication.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            let data = responseJson.data;

            if (this.saveToStorage(data)){
                this.setState({
                    validating: false
                });

                /* Redirect to accounts page */
                Actions.pageAccount();
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to store auth');
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

The saveToStorage() method:

```
async saveToStorage(userData){
    if (userData) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                authToken: userData.auth_token,
                id: userData.user_id,
                name: userData.user_login
            })
        );
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then we can provide a logout button which basically clears the storage and notifies the server to clear the token associated with the currently logged-in user.

Here is how you would implement the logout method:

```
async logout(){
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');

    // Add a method that will delete user_meta token of the user from the server. 
    // await deleteUserMetaToken(PARAM_USER_ID); 

    /* Redirect to the login page */
    Actions.pageLogin();
}
```

Full article: http://carlofontanos.com/user-login-with-wordpress-using-react-native/

Comment: Have you created basic app for this?